# How to get value of Paragraph element contained in <div> in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I know this can be very basic but I'm very poor in using JavaScript.

Following is my HTML Code :

```
<div class="request">
<h4>Request a Free Consultation</h4>
<p>XXX-XXX-XXXX</p>     
</div>
```

Using JavaScript, I want to get text contained in `<p>`  element.

I am trying in the following way, but it's giving me `undefined` error.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("request");
var pText = x.getElementsByTagName("P").innerHTML;
alert(pText);
```

Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

**EDIT** : Here is the fiddle link to try above code : 
http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/ua9zN/

Comment: Your code is fine. The only thing you need to remember is that `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByTagName` return you an array of nodes. Either iterate through them, or in your case since you only have one level, just add a `[0]`. `x[0].getElementsByTagName("P")[0].innerHTML`.

Comment: YuDroid, you are using jQuery in your linked example in JSFiddle... And a rather old version at it. Do you want the code using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `querySelectorAll`.

```
var pText = document.querySelectorAll('.request p')[0];
```

Comment: or just `querySelector` if you're accessing the first returned element anyway.

Comment: Judging by the DOM example in the question it seems likely the asker will need to address multiple elements. But feel free to disagree.

Comment: I will, purely on the JavaScript code in his example, but either one of us could be right and it's certainly not worth debating so I'll say no more about it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByTagName` return arrays. So you need to add indexes as well:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("request");
var pText = x[0].getElementsByTagName("P")[0].innerHTML;
              ^                            ^
alert(pText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("request");
```

The above line returns `NodeList`. It's *like* an *Array*, whose elements can be retrieved using the index. `getElementsByTagName` too returns the same.

```
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
  alert(x[i].getElementByTagsName('p')[0].innerHTML); // [0] to get <p>
```

Comment: it's giving `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined`

Comment: @YuDroid you're using jQuery and I don't see any code that uses innerHTML

Comment: Your code is wrong. You can't do `x[i][0]` to get the first node (`<p>`).

Comment: @AmitJoki even using `[1]` you will not get the `p` node. `x` contains only NodeList of elements with class name `request` and `<p>` doesn't have any class. You still need to search for `getElementsByTagName` for `p` Node

Comment: @antyrat ugh! Yes. Don't know what was going in my mind that I intepreted it as array of arrays!! Thanks again

Comment: There is no such method in DOM called `getElementByTags` :)